# Contact form sends email but no email arrives

Tags: php, forms

I created this contact form below and everything is great up to the point where I send the message. I get the " Thank you for contacting us etc" showing the message was sent successfully but it never arrives to my email.

I'm building this form/site for a client and tested it out in my Hotmail account. I read in another post that Hotmail may be rejecting it so I changed it to send to my work email but still not getting the email. ( work email is through Blue Host ). Could there be another reason the message is not arriving? Anything wrong with my form?

Thanks for your help.

Here's my form:

```
<form method="post" action="emailform.php">

<fieldset>
<ul>
<li>
<label for="name">Your Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name"
 class="large" required="required" 
 placeholder="Enter your name"/></li>

<li>   
<label for="idlabel">Your Email:</label>
 <input type="email"  placeholder="Enter your email"/></li>

<li>    <label for="message">Enter Your Message Below</label> <textarea name="label"    maxlength="800" rows="6"
cols="23"></textarea></li></ul>

<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

And I'm using this script to send, I have it renamed as emailform.php on my server

http://www.bruceontheloose.com/htmlcss/examples/chapter-16/emailform.txt

PHP handler

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Emailing Form Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* The CSS is here to keep the demo simple. As always, I recommend you put your CSS in an external file. */
    body {
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* --------------------------------------------------
IMPORTANT NOTE:

The sample PHP code in this file is simple by design, but as a result, it doesn't include the security checks that a bulletproof script would include. Use caution before including it on your own site. If you do intend to use a script like this, I recommend consulting PHP books and other resources to learn how to check submitted form values for malicious data before you write the values to the screen or to a database.
---------------------------------------------------- */


/* This is a very simple PHP script that outputs the name of each bit of information (that corresponds to the name attribute for that form field) along with the value that was sent with it right in the browser window, and then sends it all to an email address (once you've added it to the script; see the comments near the end regarding yourmail@yourdomain.com). 
*/


if (empty($_POST)) {
    print "<p>No data was submitted.</p>";
    print "</body></html>";
    exit();
}

/* Creates function that removes magic escaping, if it's been applied, from values and then removes extra newlines and returns to foil spammers. Thanks Larry Ullman! */
function clear_user_input($value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $value=stripslashes($value);
    $value= str_replace( "\n", '', trim($value));
    $value= str_replace( "\r", '', $value);
    return $value;
}


/* Create body of email message by cleaning each field and then appending each name and value to it. */

$body ="Here is the data that was submitted:\n";

// Get value for each form field
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $key = clear_user_input($key);
    $value = clear_user_input($value);

    if ($key == 'email_signup') { // True if an Email checkbox chosen   
        if (is_array($_POST['email_signup'])) {
            $body .= "$key: ";
            $counter =1;

            foreach ($_POST['email_signup'] as $value) {
                //Add comma and space until last element
                if (sizeof($_POST['email_signup']) == $counter) {
                    $body .= "$value\n";
                    break;
                } else {
                    $body .= "$value, ";
                    $counter += 1;
                }
            } // end foreach
        } else {
            $body .= "$key: $value\n";
        }
    } else { // field is not email_signup
        $body .= "$key: $value\n";
    }
} // end foreach

extract($_POST);

/* Get file upload picture name */
if(isset($_FILES['picture'])) {
    /*
        This basic script presents the name of the uploaded file only. To check the file size, file type (like JPG, GIF, or PNG), and actually upload a file to a folder, see the video tutorial at http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/diving-into-php/. The code explained in the video is also available for download from that URL. That page also includes links to a series of videos about using PHP.
    */

    $picture_name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

    // make sure name isn't blank
    if ($picture_name != '') {
        // add the picture name to the email body message
        $body .= "picture: $picture_name\n";
    }
}


/* Removes newlines and returns from $email and $name so they can't smuggle extra email addresses for spammers */
$email = clear_user_input($email);
$first_name = clear_user_input($first_name);

/* Create header that puts email in From box along with name in parentheses and sends Bcc to alternate address. Change yourmail@yourdomain.com to the Bcc email address you want to include. */
$from='From: '. $email . "(" . $first_name . ")" . "\r\n" . 'Bcc: yourmail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";

// Creates intelligible subject line that also shows me where it came from
$subject = 'New Profile from Web Site';

/* Sends mail to the address below with the form data submitted above. Replace yourmail@yourdomain.com with the email address to which you want the data sent. */
mail ('yourmail@yourdomain.com', $subject, $body, $from);
?>

<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's in the link I attached:

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: http://www.bruceontheloose.com/htmlcss/examples/chapter-16/emailform.txt

Comment: No. you need to post what you have edited from the original source.. If you have just copy pasted without changing anything, then email will never arrive..:)

Comment: **A:** Your form inputs are not `named`

Comment: Hi Roy, I just copied the script and replaced with my email address. I didn't see any instructions to replace anything else.

Comment: Fred, is that the reason for email not working or is that some other issue? Can you post the correct version of the code as it should be?

Comment: POST directives require form inputs and all elements be named. The only suggestion I can give you is to try/use 
`<input type="text" id="name" name="first_name" class="large" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name"/>` and `<input type="email" name="email_signup"  placeholder="Enter your email"/>` in your form.

Comment: Ok thanks Fred, I'll do that.

Comment: You're welcome. Seems like it's feeding time below...

Comment: Actually it's `<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"/>` and not `<input type="email" name="email_signup" placeholder="Enter your email"/>` my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML :

```
<form method="post" action="emailform.php">             
    <fieldset>
        <ul>
        <li>
        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"class="large" required="required" placeholder="Enter your name"/></li><!--Basically gave a name here-->

        <li>   
        <label for="idlabel">Your Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter your email"/></li><!--Basically gave a name here-->

        <li><label for="message">Enter Your Message Below</label> 
            <textarea name="message" maxlength="800" rows="6"
        cols="23"></textarea></li></ul><!--Basically gave a name here and removed label as name-->

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </fieldset>    
</form> <!--You missed this-->
```

In emailform.php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Emailing Form Data</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* The CSS is here to keep the demo simple. As always, I recommend you put your CSS in an external file. */
    body {
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* --------------------------------------------------
IMPORTANT NOTE:

The sample PHP code in this file is simple by design, but as a result, it doesn't include the security checks that a bulletproof script would include. Use caution before including it on your own site. If you do intend to use a script like this, I recommend consulting PHP books and other resources to learn how to check submitted form values for malicious data before you write the values to the screen or to a database.
---------------------------------------------------- */


/* This is a very simple PHP script that outputs the name of each bit of information (that corresponds to the name attribute for that form field) along with the value that was sent with it right in the browser window, and then sends it all to an email address (once you've added it to the script; see the comments near the end regarding yourmail@yourdomain.com). 
*/


if (empty($_POST)) {
    print "<p>No data was submitted.</p>";
    print "</body></html>";
    exit();
}

/* Creates function that removes magic escaping, if it's been applied, from values and then removes extra newlines and returns to foil spammers. Thanks Larry Ullman! */
function clear_user_input($value) {
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $value=stripslashes($value);
    $value= str_replace( "\n", '', trim($value));
    $value= str_replace( "\r", '', $value);
    return $value;
}


/* Create body of email message by cleaning each field and then appending each name and value to it. */

$body ="Here is the data that was submitted:\n";
//Fetching the form fields here
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

/* Removes newlines and returns from $email and $name so they can't smuggle extra email addresses for spammers */
$email   = clear_user_input($email);
$name    = clear_user_input($name);
$body   .= clear_user_input($message);//Appending the message to the body of the email

/* Create header that puts email in From box along with name in parentheses and sends Bcc to alternate address. Change yourmail@yourdomain.com to the Bcc email address you want to include. */
$from='From: '. $email . "(" . $name . ")" . "\r\n" . 'Bcc: yourmail@yourdomain.com' . "\r\n";

// Creates intelligible subject line that also shows me where it came from
$subject = 'New Profile from Web Site';

/* Sends mail to the address below with the form data submitted above. Replace yourmail@yourdomain.com with the email address to which you want the data sent. */
mail ('yourmail@yourdomain.com', $subject, $body, $from);
?>

<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: Roy, thank you. The email now arrived, which is great. But new issue, no content, all it says is "Here is the data that was submitted:" and then nothing even though I entered a message. Also, shouldn't is say who the email is from?

Comment: `</form> <!--You missed this-->` it was in there. The OP missed an indent. See the edit. Plus, adding an "explanation" will benefit the OP, and not just posting code and saying "this should do it...". People are here to learn from their mistakes and it needs to be pointed out.

Comment: I tested my modified code but didn't post as an answer. Everything came in fine, including the message body @DariaW. did you re-upload and cleared your cache/refresh?

Comment: @DariaW : Ive edited the answer. Put proper comments also for you to understand. Let me know if this worked for you..:)

Comment: Great, it works now. Thank you both Roy and Fred. I've used Roy's method because he made it easy for me by posting entire code :) I appreciate that. Thanks guys.

Comment: @DariaW : Okay great.. It will be good if you can accept the answer that i posted..:)..